# How to get rid of controller name in URL after form sent request?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

After my form is sent I get:

```
http://... /param1/param2/CONTROLLER-NAME
```

How to get rid of the last part in URL - CONTROLLER-NAME ?

The standard form view:

```
        echo $this->Form->create('*',
        array('url' => array('controller' => '*', 'action' => '*')           
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('*', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true));
        echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
        echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: we'll need to see some code... post the view where the form is created

Comment: @pleasedontbelong - I suppose it's standard form view

Comment: what are those stars? Please paste the actual code.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz - just names for controllers, values - form functions well but Cake adds sth that is unnecessary for me

Comment: @easyrider please don't make your code needlessly obscure, post the actual values. What you put in the `url` option of the form create is what actually creates the URL it posts too.

Answer (score 2):

why are you using `'*'` in the form??

Usually, your form should look like this:

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Search', // model name, even if it doesn't really exists
        array('url' => array('controller' => 'searches', 'action' => 'index')
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('search', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true));
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

is not normal that cake's creating the url like that, usually the generated url has the format `/controller/action/params` and you could redefine that using the routes.php if you want to

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer - you made me find the answer myself -  there was a mistake in my routes path - but it is topic for another question